# What is this "FOR" command in windows batch file doing?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

```
for /F %%i in ("%dist_exe_source%") do set dist_exe=%%~nxi
```

I'm confused on what is being checked in the string and then what is being set in the dist_exe?

I've dug into the command prompt help but I'm still confused as to what is actually going on in this line.

Thanks in advance

---

**Edit**

Background: After some of the comments posted I would like to provide some more information. I'm working on an application that I inherited. This application is written using the Qt IDE. The application is a means for the customer to test and interface with our product. The batch file is part of a "Custom Build Step" process that calls the file along with two arguments which are paths as follows.

> scripts\windows_collect_files_to_package.bat build\release\unpacked release\application.exe

The complete code is here:

```
:: the directory that this script was started in
set cur_dir=%cd%

:: the directory where all the files that need to be packaged will be placed
set dist_dir=%1

:: the exe to find needed dlls for
set dist_exe_source=%2

for /F %%i in ("%dist_exe_source%") do set dist_exe=%%~nxi

:: clean up any leftovers...
rmdir /q /s %dist_dir%

:: copy all the dlls and other stuff to dist_dir...
mkdir %dist_dir%
copy /y %dist_exe_source% %dist_dir%
cd %dist_dir%
windeployqt --compiler-runtime %dist_exe% 
cd %cur_dir%
```

The batch file is ultimately grouping the necessary file dependencies for the application in a specific directory. Then it runs *windeployqt.exe* (which is the deploy command from Qt for windows platforms).

My issue was understanding what the for loop was doing so that I could document the entire process.

Comment: I would assume that the source variable has the full path to a file and the `FOR` command is reading that variable and the set command is getting just the file name without the path.

Comment: It's difficult to explain with any certainty what that line is doing without any further context. What is `%dist_exe_source%` set to in the code before this line is reached?

Comment: I would suggest it is incorrect. If the variable `%dist_exe_source%` has a value which is an executable command it should read `For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"%dist_exe_source%"') Do Set "dist_exe=%%~nxA"`, where the new variable `%dist_exe%` will hold the filename and extension returned from the command. If the variable `%dist_exe_source%` has a value which is just an executable file name with a path, it should read `For %%A In ("%dist_exe_source%") Do Set "dist_exe=%%~nxA"`, where the new variable `%dist_exe%` will hold the filename and extension portion of the value of `%dist_exe_source%`.

Comment: @KenWhite `dist_exe_source` is set to an executable: `set dist_exe_source=\release\application.exe`. It is set as an argument from command line though; so the batch file line is actually set `dist_exe_source=%2`. The second argument is in fact I wrote it above.

Comment: @N.Dijkhoffz Compo is absolutely right. The command is incorrect. It should be `for %%i in ("%dist_exe_source%") do set "dist_exe=%%~nxi"` to get file name and file extension assigned to environment variable `dist_exe` without relative or absolute path. The option `/F` is not needed here and can produce wrong result if path to executable contains a space character as Compo explained. For help on command __FOR__ open a command prompt window and run `for /?` which outputs on several pages the help for this command.

Comment: @jwdonahue I made some changes to the post. Added some more information clarifying what the issue was and also added the script for the batch file. Hope this improves the post overall. Thanks for pointing it out. Still raw at posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /F %%i in ("%dist_exe_source%") ...
```

Assuming `%dist_exe_source%` is not empty, each %%i will be a space delimited segment taken from whatever string is stored in `dist_exe_source`.

```
... do set dist_exe=%%~nxi
```

Strips any quotes off of `%%i` and then parses any `name.ext` it can find. A quick test from the command line using a test variable indicates that if `%dist_exe%` resolves to `JustAName` you'll get `JustAName` from `%~nxi`, so it basically strips quotes and any leading drive/path data from the string.

Comment: dist_exe_source is just the executable. Is it copying the entire executable file to dist_exe?

Comment: @N.Dijkhoffz,  It's effectively stripping the quotes and path from source string, leaving `filename.ext`.  See `help for` for an explanation of the replacement variable modifiers.

Comment: Oh I see now. So dist_exe = filename.ext. Now I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
:: get just the filename.ext from exe path
for %%i in ("%dist_exe_source%") do set "dist_exe=%%~nxi"
```

The `/f` argument is not needed. A simple `for` loop can parse the executable
path and get the filename.ext from the path using modifiers of `nx`.

The operation of the `for` loop in this instance, is a string operation
to get the parts of the path using modifiers. No actual copying or other
operation is being done.

Added comment to code to describe the line.